# Angular - Reactive Form - Default selected value in dropdown

Tags: angular, html-select, dropdown, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular's reactive form in which I have a dropdown.
Refer [plunk here](https://embed.plnkr.co/naHzHG/)

See below code.

```
<select class="form-control" id="contry" formControlName="country">
    <option *ngFor="let contry of countries" [value]="contry.id">{{contry.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Here I am not able to display default selected value. It always shows me a blank default value in dropdown. It is working fine in Template driven forms. And I also know it can be possible in reactive form by using

> **form.setValue** or **form.patchValue**

Is there any better way that I can achieve this without setting any form value in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

In your form initialization just add the default value to the form control

```
this.myForm = this._fb.group({
     country: this._fb.control(1)
});
```

You can obviously change 1 with the id of your default value

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        country:this.countries[0]
});
```

and in template

```
<option *ngFor="let contry of countries" [value]="contry">{{contry.name}}</option>
```

> set default value for the formcontrol and in template, bind value property with the whole `contry` object as you are pointing the full object in the .ts file

Comment: Write this comment under the question. I was just referring his code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the patchValue like below, you can have your default value selected

in your component.ts

```
  this.yourForm.patchValue({
      CategoryID:1
    });
```